# check if a txt file exist in a specific directory or not?

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if a txt file with 'newfile' name exists in a specified directory or not, if not create a new txt file

```
import os.path
if (os.path.exists("newfile.txt") == False):
    open("count.txt", "w")
```

but it does not work since I cannot access the current or specified director with this code.

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot access the current/specified directory

Comment: os.path is 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\ntpath.py', however my working directory where the txt file exist is another directory

Comment: So what is your question? How to find the current working directory? `os.path` is a Python module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the current directory and file's directory (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137497/6045800)

Comment: I want to find a newfile.txt file in current directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make python script show an error when user inputs same file name with this piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74324942/how-can-i-make-python-script-show-an-error-when-user-inputs-same-file-name-with)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import inspect
import os

module_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
module_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(module_path))
os.chdir(module_dir) # set working directory to where file is

if not os.path.exists("C:\\absolute\\directory\\newfile.txt"):
    open("count.txt", "w")
```

You can replace the path with unix style directories.

Comment: The first line can just be `module_path = __file__`...

Comment: It might not work in all cases such as symlinked, imported in another module, executable etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Solve 1:

```
import os.path

file = 'yourpath\file_to_check.txt'     # 예제 Textfile

if os.path.isfile(file):
  print("Yes. it is a file")
elif os.path.isdir(file):
  print("Yes. it is a directory")
elif os.path.exists(file):
  print("Something exist")
else :
  print("Nothing")
```

Solve 2:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("your_path\file_to_check.txt") # This way only works in windows os
if my_file.is_file():
  print("Yes it is a file")
```

Comment: the problem is that os.path is not my current directory, or the directory that my txt file exist. @xlab

Comment: If you add `yourpath` to the filename it should work as described here. Alternatively you can change your working directory with os.chdir(yourpath) and then operate with raw filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to locate the directory.

```py
import glob

file_path = glob.glob('../your/file_directory/*')
if "count.txt" not in file_path:
    with open('../your/file_directory/count.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Create new text file')
```